# Adaptive payments funding type

Tags: paypal

Trying to setup a parallel payment in paypal but need to give the user specific options on funding type

I would like to only give them "debitcard" or "creditcard" or "Balance" in seperate calls.

is this possible?

looking at this link it has them in "fundingsource fields" and are seperated with "allowed" being true or false

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/

is this possible or would i need the extended permissions?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the [Developer Guide](https://www.paypal-biz.com/development/documentation/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf) (Page 14) there are only two permission levels. Standard and Advanced.

The page you linked says "Note: `FundingConstraint` is unavailable to API callers with standard permission levels; for more information, refer to the section Adaptive Payments Permission Levels."

Yes this will work to limit which funding sources can be used (`eCheck`,`CreditCard`,`Balance`), however, you need the advanced permissions for this.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the feedback. I understand the funding contsraint call and the advance level. Im referring to the section "FundingSource Fields" where is lists all the funding types individually. does this also need advanced permissions?

Comment: Yes, those are sub-fields of `fundingConstraints`.. eg: `fundingConstraint.allowedFundingType.fundingTypeInfo(0).fundingType=credit`

Comment: Note that the preferred way to get the adaptive permission enabled is to put in a support ticket with Merchant Technical Support.  https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask